# NullPointerException when getting String from another activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm creating a Mail client with javamail. I've set a login activity which stores mail and password. I have  the code which sends the mail in a class called Data.java. The problem is that I can't get SharedPreferences from there becouse it is not an Activity and it doesn't extend PreferenceActivity. I've needed to use `Looper.prepare()` becouse otherwise it threw another exception. I'm trying to get Shared Prefs from MainActivity but I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to print it. My MainActivity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mail1 = prefs.getString("email", null);
        pass = prefs.getString("pass", null);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public String getMail1(){
        return mail1;
    }
    public String getPass(){
        return pass;
    }
```

Data.java code:

```
public class Data{

    String a;
    String b;

    private void getEverything(){
        Looper.prepare();
        MainActivity d = new MainActivity();
        a = d.getMail1();
        b = d.getPass();
    }


    public void sendMail(){
        getEverything();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(a, b);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(a));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(gmail.to));
            message.setSubject(gmail.subject);
            message.setText(gmail.text);

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(b);
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
            at com.test.email.Data.sendMail(Data.java:61)
            at com.test.email.gmail.doInBackground(gmail.java:40)
            at com.test.email.gmail.doInBackground(gmail.java:19)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: on which line you are getting nullPointerException?

Comment: @niteshgoel If I let it like in the code I've posted I first get a Autenthication excecption but when I type manually the mail and pass I get it in the First System.out.println

Comment: can you post the error log

Comment: @niteshgoel edited post with logcat

Comment: post the code where this error is coming from.

Comment: Strange. NullPointerException is at Data class, line 61, but the class you posted is 47 lines long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

`a` and `b` are `null`. That's the reason for NPE.

The reason they are `null`:

```
MainActivity d = new MainActivity();
```

Never instantiate activities with `new`. (Use `Intent` instead. But you don't need to instantiate an activity here.)

So the activity object you get here is not the same activity you've set the variable values in.

Instead, pass whatever values you need in the `Data` class as method parameters, like

```
public void sendMail(String email, String password) { ...
```